# Форматирование вывода в numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Стало интересно, как производится форматирование в numpy as np. При генерации рандомной строки / массива, необходимо оставить два знака после запятой, но хотелось бы сохранить их для дальнейшего вывода.
Собственно сам код:

```
import numpy as np
def randoms():  
    return np.random.uniform(65.0, 70.0, 4)
exchange_1 = randoms()
exchange_1_twosigns = []
for i in exchange_1:
    x = round(i, 2)    
    exchange_1_twosigns.append(x)
```

Код получился длинный и не красивы, я только учусь. Возможно есть решение и проще, но я не смог его подобрать / найти.
Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще можно воспользоваться методом [set_printoptions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) и установить параметр `precision`, который отвечает за то сколько знаков после запятой выводится.
Это изменит только печать для всех массивов, при этом сам массив будет оставаться с необходимой точностью.

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
arr = np.random.random_sample((5))
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь методом [ndarray.round()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.round.html):

```
In [4]: exchange_1.round(2)
Out[4]: array([65.43, 65.44, 69.92, 67.57])
```

---

**UPDATE:**  опции вывода на печать можно установить в рамках контекста - пример:

```
In [43]: print(exchange_1)
[68.42909774 67.97871401 66.90487171 68.89564863]

In [44]: with np.printoptions(precision=2):
    ...:     print(exchange_1)
    ...:
[68.43 67.98 66.9  68.9 ]
```

после выхода из блока `with ...` действуют старые опции:

```
In [45]: print(exchange_1)
[68.42909774 67.97871401 66.90487171 68.89564863]
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое [Avernial](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178429/avernial), данное решение идеально подошло. 
Отвечаю на свой вопрос заданный ему:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
def randoms():  
    return np.random.uniform(65.0, 70.0, 4)
exchange_1 = randoms()
```

Проверил и понял, что ограничения в два символа действует на все рандомы созданные через numpy as np. Т.е. все числа, которые рандомно генерируются уже отображаются с двумя знаками после запятой, но ри этом сам массив будет оставаться с необходимой точностью.
Тут уже помогает формат вывода:

```
print('{:.5f}'.format(numpy.mean(average)))
```